# Ruby sum every index value of loop

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, instance-variables

I have a variable @Variable=[], it gets filled with ramdon values every iteration of my index, something like this:

```
def whetever(array)
array.each_index {|i|
@variable=magic_ramdon_string_of_numbers_diferent_on_every_iteration
}
end
```

I want to create another array summing up the values of every iteration of @variable

Example of values of @variable:

```
i=0 @variable=[56,78,34,84]
i=1 @variable=[24,57,14,78]
i=2 @variable=[54,74,52,45]
```

What i want is this:

```
sum_variable=[56,78,34,84,24,57,14,78,54,74,52,45]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by defining the `sum_variable` as an empty array at first, then appending the summation values to it, in each iteration of the loop:

```
def whatever(array)
  sum_variable = []
  array.each_index do |i|
    @variable = magic_ramdon_string_of_numbers_diferent_on_every_iteration
    sum_variable << @variable.inject(:+)
  end
end
```

Note that if this were a Rails application, not just vanilla ruby, then `ActiveSupport` also provides the method `Array#sum`, which you could use instead of `.inject(:+)`.

Comment: It looks like OP wants just to concatenate arrays of `@variable` from all iterations into one array. Not to sum them. So `sum_variable += @variable` should be enough

Comment: Oh right, yeah, I misread because of my false assumption of what `sum_variable` would implicitly mean to me. Plus, the phrase *"summing up the values of every iteration"* threw me off.

Comment: Hi thanks, it dit not work, its my own fault, @variable are Point3d(0, 2, 0), i am doing an extension on sketchup it uses ruby as base but has its owm api, sometimes they like each other sometimes not, i made it work like this sum_variable.push(@variable), it did worked great thanks anyway!

Comment: @TomLord Calling `sum_variable.flatten!` is not necessary, because `+` concatenates arrays, not appends 2nd as element of 1st one

Comment: [Array#sum is plain ruby](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sum) since 2.4

Answer (score 0):

I would write this like:

```
def whetever(array)
  sum_variable = (0...array.size).flat_map do |i|
    magic_ramdon_string_of_numbers_diferent_on_every_iteration
  end
end
```

`flat_map` calls the block on each element of the sequence to get an array,
and returns all of the result arrays concatenated together. Here, the sequence
is the range `0...array.size`, which are the arrays indices, if we just wanted
the elements themselves, like `array[i]`, we could just use `array.flat_map`,
instead.